# Drools Rule Template - ResultSet Generator does not display complete Rule file generated

Tags: drools

I am trying to create a rule template file with decision table. I am populating the template file from DB values. Using  ResultSetGenerator  to complile and generate DRL. However I am getting just the package and import line in the generated DRL. Please help.

```
ResultSetGenerator resultSetGenerator = new ResultSetGenerator();
            /* Build drl from DB data */
final String drl = resultSetGenerator.compile(result, template);
```

The Template looks like this

```
template header
col1
col2

package  rules;
import vo.TestVO;

template "template1"
rule "Rule @{row.rowNumber} "
dialect "mvel"
when
  o: TestVO(field ==  "@{col1}")
then
  o.addField(@{col2})
end

end template
```

DRL generated output on console

```
package  rules;
import vo.TestVO;
```

Comment: Display type and contents of `result`. Is it a ResultSet? Is it empty?